# How to make a screenshot of the widget and paste it into the QGraphicsView?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qgraphicsview

I have 2 `QGraphicsView` and one `QWebEngineView` widget on the form and I need to * (on the click of the button1)* make a screenshot of the content inside this `QWebEngineView` with some defined setback from the original `QWebEngineView` borders and save that screenshot as an image, and at the same time keep it as an object and paste this object to the first `QGraphicsView` and * (on the click of button2)* insert saved image into the second `QGraphicsView`.

Edit:
(I'd like to make a screenshot of the area inside the QtWebEngineWidgets and keep this area as an object. and a second problem I need to know how to paste this area in to the QGraphicsView in 2 different ways: (from the file) and display it as an object without saving. 2 QGraphicsView are just for the studying purpose it could be just one QGraphicsView and by hitting on button1 screenshot is making and pasting as an object to the QGraphicsView and by hitting on button2 -screenshot is making (saving as an png and loading to the QGraphicsView))

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QBrush, QPen, QScreen, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QStyleFactory, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem, QPushButton
from pyqtgraph.Qt    import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog

class Geometry(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self)


class CentralPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.lblCoords = QLabel('MAP SELECTOR (object image):  ')
        self.lblCoords2 = QLabel('MAP SELECTOR (loaded from file image):  ')
        self.gvwShapes = Geometry()
        self.gvwShapes2 = Geometry()
        
        vbxDsply = QVBoxLayout()
        vbxDsply.addWidget(self.lblCoords)      # Capture coordinates of drawn line at window 1
        vbxDsply.addWidget(self.gvwShapes)      # add QGraphicsView #1
        
        vbxDsply.addWidget(self.lblCoords2)     # Capture coordinates of drawn line at window 2
        vbxDsply.addWidget(self.gvwShapes2)     # add QGraphicsView #2
        
        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()   # Add Google maps web window
        self.webEngineView.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/@36.797966,-97.1413048,3464a,35y,0.92h/data=!3m1!1e3"))
        vbxDsply.addWidget(self.webEngineView)
        
        self.Button1 = QPushButton('Do screenshot of webEngineView save it and paste it into QGraphicsView2', self) # Button to load image to graphics view
        vbxDsply.addWidget(self.Button1)
        self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.button_screenshot)
        
        self.Button2 = QPushButton('Do screenshot of webEngineView and paste it into QGraphicsView1 ', self)
        vbxDsply.addWidget(self.Button2)
        self.Button2.clicked.connect(self.button_load_image)
        
        self.setLayout(vbxDsply)
        
        self.filename = "image.jpg"

    def button_screenshot(self):
        print('Screenshot is taken and saved as an image, Image loaded and inserted into the gvwShapes QGraphicsView1 ')
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QScreen.grabWindow(app.primaryScreen(), QApplication.desktop().winId()).save(self.filename, 'png')

    def button_load_image(self):
        print('Screenshot is taken and inserted into the gvwShapes2 QGraphicsView2')
        
        # pix = QPixmap()
        # pix.load(self.filename)
        # pix = QPixmap(self.filename)
        # item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pix)
        
        # scene = QGraphicsScence(self)
        # scene.addItem(item)
        # self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)
        
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.filename)
        item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        scene.addItem(item)
        self.gvwShapes.setScene(scene)
        
        
        # scene = self.gvwShapes
        # self.image = QtGui.QPixmap(self.filename)
        # self.gvwShapes.add
        # scene.addItem(QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.image))
        # self.view = self.QGraphicsView 
        # self.view.setScene(self.image)
        # self.view.show()
        
        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(200, 50, 700, 900) 
        self.setWindowTitle('MAP Selector REV01')
        self.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))
        self.CenterPane = CentralPanel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)




# Catching exceptions and running a main loop
#
import traceback
def except_hook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
    tb = "".join(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb))
    print("error cached")
    print("error message:\n", tb)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainEventThred = QApplication([])
    os.environ["QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS"] = "--enable-logging --log-level=3"
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    MainApp = MainWindow()
    MainApp.show()
    MainEventThred.exec()
```

Comment: I did not understand what is the purpose of the first and second QGraphicsView, and what is your current problem?

Comment: @eyllanesc problem is: I don't know how to make a screenshot of the area inside the QtWebEngineWidgets and keep this area as an object. and a second problem I need to know how to paste this area in to the QGraphicsView in 2 different ways: (from the file) and display it as an object without saving.  2 QGraphicsView are just for the studying purpose it could be just one QGraphicsView and by hitting on button1 screenshot is making and pasting as an object to the QGraphicsView and by hitting on button2 -screenshot is making (saving as an png and loading to the QGraphicsView)

Comment: I just need to know a mechanic of these operations

Comment: It would be good if you indicate that in your post since that requirement is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Crop image in QWebEngineView

If you want to implement the crop of the QWebEngineView screenshot then you must use a QRubberBand that is on the focusProxy () of the QWebEngineView (it is the widget where the web page is rendered and receives the mouse event that is created after displaying the view)

```py
from functools import cached_property
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QEvent, QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QRubberBand
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class RubberBandManager(QObject):
    pixmap_changed = pyqtSignal(QPixmap, name="pixmapChanged")

    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._origin = QPoint()
        self._widget = widget

        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    @cached_property
    def rubberband(self):
        return QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self.widget)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if self.widget is source:
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                self._origin = event.pos()
                self.rubberband.setGeometry(QRect(self._origin, QSize()))
                self.rubberband.show()
            elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
                self.rubberband.setGeometry(
                    QRect(self._origin, event.pos()).normalized()
                )
            elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                rect = self.rubberband.geometry()
                pixmap = self.widget.grab(rect)
                self.pixmap_changed.emit(pixmap)
                self.rubberband.hide()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebEngineView()
    view.load(
        QUrl(
            "https://www.google.com/maps/@36.797966,-97.1413048,3464a,35y,0.92h/data=!3m1!1e3"
        )
    )
    view.show()
    rubberband_manager = RubberBandManager(view.focusProxy())

    label = QLabel()
    label.hide()

    def on_pixmap_changed(pixmap):
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.adjustSize()
        label.show()

    rubberband_manager.pixmap_changed.connect(on_pixmap_changed)

    ret = app.exec()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

### Show an Image in QGraphicsView

To display an image then you must use a QGraphicsPixmapItem where you load a QPixmap.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsPixmapItem,
)


class ImageViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)

        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(scene)

        self._pixmap_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        scene.addItem(self._pixmap_item)

    def load_pixmap(self, pixmap):
        self._pixmap_item.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.fitToWindow()

    def fitToWindow(self):
        self.fitInView(self.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.fitToWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = ImageViewer()
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    pixmap = QPixmap("image.jpg")
    view.load_pixmap(pixmap)

    ret = app.exec()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

The previous widget is used to load an image from a file: `pixmap = QPixmap("/path/of/image")` or use the QPixmap provided by pixmap_changed signal of `RubberBandManager`.

Comment: thanks, but for some reason I have some issues with the decorator: 
  ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'functools'.  Trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @NickPV What version of python do you use? My code is valid for python 3.8 or higher

Comment: oh I see, that's may be a problem, I'm using 3.7.4 for all my projects

Comment: @NickPV then install backports.cached-property: `python -m pip install backports.cached-property` and change `from functools import cached_property` to `from backports.cached_property import cached_property`. If you do not indicate the version of the tools you use, it is assumed that you are using the latest versions.

Comment: it works really cool, really nice example. but with google map it overlapping with the map moving from google map itself and when u  selecting the area mouse is moving this area alongside with the main google map and kinda target get's shifted

Comment: @NickPV That is a trivial example that I show how a crop should be done, obviously there are things that I have not polished but it should be taken as a basis and it will be the developer's job to eliminate those imperfections, such as clearly defining when it is in google "pan" mode and the "crop" mode (maybe some combination of keyboard keys)

Answer (score 1):

Set a scene for your QGraphicsViews.

```
self.gvwShapes = Geometry()
self.gvwShapes2 = Geometry()
self.gvwShapes.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
self.gvwShapes2.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
```

Use `QWidget.grab()` to render it into a QPixmap and `QGraphicsScene.addPixmap()` to add it to the scene. You can specify the area with a QRect.

```
def button_screenshot(self):
    pixmap = self.webEngineView.grab(QRect(180, 100, 300, 280))
    pixmap.save(self.filename)
    self.gvwShapes2.scene().addPixmap(pixmap)

def button_load_image(self):
    self.gvwShapes.scene().addPixmap(QPixmap(self.filename))
```

Comment: YEA, that looks pretty much what I need. the only thing is how to crop the center of the screenshot (or define a setback)?

Comment: @NickPV `grab()` accepts a QRect argument if you don't want to grab the whole widget. (import QRect from QtCore).